# I wrote an apk but it shows me unfortunately stopped working

Tags: android

What I see in "Run" footer. It's just a simple UI design and gets installed successfully,
but when I try to open it, it crashes and says " unfortunately stopped working".
I'm kind of new to Android Studio.
also signed the apk but no differences.

```
02/23 17:05:26: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\The King Gh0$T\AndroidStudioProjects\MOCBioPrinter\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/mking.mocbioprinter
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/mking.mocbioprinter"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/mking.mocbioprinter
Success
APK installed in 3 s 878 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "mking.mocbioprinter/mking.mocbioprinter.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 8148 on device samsung-sm_t561-3801b1493e30a200
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:mking.mocbioprinter
W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lmking/mocbioprinter/MainActivity;
    Class init failed in newInstance call (Lmking/mocbioprinter/MainActivity;)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4171dbc0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mking.mocbioprinter, PID: 8148
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load native-lib from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mking.mocbioprinter-7.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mking.mocbioprinter-7, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
        at mking.mocbioprinter.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:29)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8148 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Can you provide more details. (IE Manifest File, Activity, etc) Do you see any screens?

Comment: here is the hole project : https://ufile.io/wc1jr

Comment: @Ge3ng here you go pal

Comment: only 2 hours and 40 mins left for me . any helps will be appreciated